# How do I get the name of the month (not just a number)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Currently the code gives this: 07/08/2021 (Example).
I want to do that: July/08/2021

```
function loadData() {
   
  var idplanilha = "LINK"
  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idplanilha);
  
  var guiadados = planilha.getSheetByName("Data");
  var dados = guiadados.getRange(2,1, guiadados.getLastRow()-1,9).getValues();
  var colunadata = 1;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++){          
        
        var data = new Date(dados[i][colunadata]) ;      

          data.setDate(data.getDate());

        var d = data.getDate();
        var m = data.getMonth() + 1;
        var a = data.getFullYear();
        
        if(d < 10){
           var d = "0" + d;
        }

        if(m < 10){
           var m = "0" + m;
        }

        var data = m + "/" + d + "/" + a                

        dados[i][colunadata] = data; 

}

return dados;

}
```

Currently the code gives this: 07/08/2021 (Example).
I want to do that: July/08/2021

Comment: Where do you use `month`?

Comment: Use `data.getMonth()` as the index into the `month` array.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks "how to get the month name", for which there is the built-in method [Date.toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) that can return the month name in numerous languages.

```
date.toLocaleDateString(lang, {month:"long"})
```

You can also add options to include the day and year as well:

```
{month: "long", day: "2-digit", year: "4-digit"}
```

However, I don't think there is a locale that will automatically format the date as July/08/2021 in multiple languages. So that probably requires further manipulation (see comments in snippet).

**Snippet**

```js
const monthName = (date, lang = "en-US") => 
  date.toLocaleDateString(lang, {month:"long"});


let d = new Date("07/08/2021");

console.log("English", monthName(d));
console.log("Português", monthName(d, "pt-PT"));
console.log("Español", monthName(d, "es-ES"));
console.log("Hindi", monthName(d, "hi-IN"));



/* full format
const formatDate = (date, lang = "en-US") =>
  `${date.toLocaleDateString(lang, { month:"long"})}/${date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { day: "2-digit"})}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function carregarDados() {
   
  var idplanilha = "LINK"
  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idplanilha);
  
  var guiadados = planilha.getSheetByName("Data");
  var dados = guiadados.getRange(2,1, guiadados.getLastRow()-1,9).getValues(); //ALTERAR  
  var colunadata = 1;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++){          
        
        var data = new Date(dados[i][colunadata]) ;      

          data.setDate(data.getDate());

        var d = data.getDate();
        var month = data.getMonth() + 1;
        var m =  ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
        var a = data.getFullYear();
        
        if(d < 10){
          var d = "0" + d;
        }

        if(m < 10){
          var m = "0" + m;
        }

        var data = (m[month]) + "/" + d + "/" + a                

        dados[i][colunadata] = data; 

}

return dados;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).